# Cross-compilation of Mali driver fails

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm trying to cross-compile Mali DX910-SW-99002-r7p0-00rel0 Driver in my Linux x86 (Ubuntu) machine for an ARM64 machine linux kernel version 4.4.83.
I followed the instructions given in the readme file:
DX910-SW-99002-r7p0-00rel0/driver/src/devicedrv/ump/readme.txt

1. select Mali as a module (M) within the menuconfig:

   ```
   CONFIG_MALI400=m
   CONFIG_MALI450=y
   ```
2. `KDIR=~/linux-4.4.83 USING_UMP=1 BUILD=debug make`
   cannot find bingcc
3. `KDIR=./linux-4.4.83 CONFIG=default BUILD=debug make`
   cannot find bingcc

My question is:
The two compile commands (items 2. and 3. above) both yield the same failure result as the following:

```
   KDIR=~/linux-4.4.83 USING_UMP=1 BUILD=debug make
   make: gcc-linaro-6.3.1-2017.05-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/aarch64-linux-   gnu/bingcc: Command not found
    CHK     include/config/kernel.release
    CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
    CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
    CC      kernel/bounds.s
    /bin/sh: 1: gcc-linaro-6.3.1-2017.05-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/aarch64-linux-gnu/bingcc: not found
    Kbuild:44: recipe for target 'kernel/bounds.s' failed
    make[1]: *** [kernel/bounds.s] Error 127
    Makefile:1007: recipe for target 'prepare0' failed
```

What should be done to fix these?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use GNU C compiler from `gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu` Ubuntu package, then you'd better make sure that the package is indeed installed and then specify one more option to `make`, in example:
`KDIR=~/linux-4.4.83 USING_UMP=1 BUILD=debug ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu- make`.

However, I see `linaro` mentioned in your output. So, alternatively, you may consider following [this](https://wiki.linaro.org/HowTo/BuildArm64Kernel) guide on toolchain setup and usage.

Comment: Your suggestion helped to make some progress.

Comment: So, have you faced some other issues?

Comment: Your suggestion helped to make some progress.  linaro recommends going the same path. Consequently, running the command as the following:      KDIR=~/linux-4.4.83.FS-noMali USING_UMP=1 BUILD=debug ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu- make
The result is:                                                                                                  
  CHK     kernel/config_data.h
make[1]: 'arch/arm64/boot/Image.gz' is up to date.
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 5 modules
The kernel "Image.gz" has been previously built for the kernel configured with Mali as a module  (M).

Comment: The last phrase is my addition so compile messages ended with ".... MODPOST 5 modules"

Comment: So, do you find it confusing? From your question it follows that in your current build you select it to be module (M) too. So, indeed, the image may be retained intact. Or do you want to achieve something different?

But at last I glad to see that the primary goal of your question has been resolved since as I understand you got no failures now. Right?

Comment: These two compilations - items 2. and 3. at the top of the message, resulted in these same messages, and completed within a few seconds.   Are these messages, the expected result showing completion of Mali driver compilation?

Comment: Could you please provide the full output (new) which comes from both of the items now?

Comment: KDIR=~/linux-4.4.83.FS-noMali USING_UMP=1 BUILD=debug ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu- make
  CHK     include/config/kernel.release
  CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
  CHK     include/generated/bounds.h
  CHK     include/generated/timeconst.h
  CHK     include/generated/asm-offsets.h
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
  CHK     include/generated/compile.h
  CHK     kernel/config_data.h
make[1]: 'arch/arm64/boot/Image.gz' is up to date.
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 5 modules

Comment: Well, could you somehow check that `CONFIG=default` is correct? The readme says that it should be a sub-directory name where `config.h` resides. Anyhow, when you build a module, you should be able to see how object files (`.o`) are reported to appear, how the `.ko` file is created. Nothing is shown in your case.

Comment: I am not sure how to check it.          The readme file within the mali directory, doesn't specify that. Which readme are you referring to?    Regarding the location of config.h, do you mean the one located under DX910-SW-99002-r7p0-00rel0/driver/src/devicedrv/ump/arch-default?

Comment: Well, it's a tough question. But let me ask you - why have you decided to cross-compile it? Why can't you do it on device?

Comment: Perhaps this post is helpful - http://forum.lemaker.org/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=4312&page=1#pid31877

Comment: I am sorry but I am a novice, so I am not sure what "on device" mean. However, I am using the arm64 within qemu environment.   Does that answer your question?

Comment: Executing according to your link, the results are the following:

Comment: ~/Downloads/DX910-SW-99002-r7p0-00rel0/driver/src/devicedrv/ump$ KDIR=~/linux-4.4.83.FS-noMali  CONFIG=default  BUILD=debug ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu- make
  /home/avnerpc/Downloads/DX910-SW-99002-r7p0-00rel0/driver/src/devicedrv/ump/linux/ump_kernel_linux.c: In function ‘ump_initialize_module’:
/home/avnerpc/Downloads/DX910-SW-99002-r7p0-00rel0/driver/src/devicedrv/ump/linux/ump_kernel_linux.c:110:90: error: macro "__DATE__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]
  DBG_MSG(2, ("Inserting UMP device driver. Compiled: %s, time: %s\n", __DATE__, __TIME__));

Comment: Well, it'is some kind of different result from what was observed before. However, I think, we need to study more pages on the net like that. But, at least, you are able to see, that the driver compilation is actually started now.

Comment: Yes, it is definitely a progress. I will study and hope to find more material.

Comment: Going further, (commented out DATE and TIME) the follwing errors occur:
/home/avnerpc/Downloads/DX910-SW-99002-r7p0-00rel0/driver/src/devicedrv/ump/linux/ump_osk_low_level_mem.c: In function ‘level1_cache_flush_all’:
/home/avnerpc/Downloads/DX910-SW-99002-r7p0-00rel0/driver/src/devicedrv/ump/linux/ump_osk_low_level_mem.c:218:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘__cpuc_flush_kern_all’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  __cpuc_flush_kern_all();

.

Comment: I think that commenting out some pieces of code is not a good idea. But your effort showed that even if you comment some code, then some other errors occur elsewhere. So, there might be some general mistake of the approach being taken. You say that you followed the link - did you compile it on device? I mean, as I understand, they compiled it on their Raspberry Pi rather than on PC.

Comment: I followed the link "forum.lemaker.org" as far as changing DATE and TIME (they did it differently though). I compile it on a Toshiba laptop with Ubuntu OS, within qemu environment.